# Using java scanner

Tags: java

Im sorry if this seems newbish, but i know we all gotta start some where.. its stopping me from putting the users data after dessert , well before it...this is an edit question

package scanners;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class usingscanners {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userName;
    int age; 
    String dessert;
    
    
    System.out.println("Hi What is your name? ");
    
     userName = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println ("How are you doing, " + userName + "?");
    System.out.println ("What is you age, " + userName + "?");
    
    age = sc.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println ("Hello, " + userName +  " you are " + age);
    
    System.out.println ("ok, " + userName + " .Your are " + age + "." + " What is your favorite dessert?"); 
      
    dessert = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println (" Hello, " + userName + "You are " + age + " and your favorite dessert is " + dessert);
    
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: The value returned by `nextLine` is a String not an `int`.  Look at `Integer.valueOf` to see how to convert

Comment: be more specific. What is the error that you get?

Comment: Its stopping my code after i go back to string. Wont allow me to input user data

Answer (score 0):

age is an integer, use age = sc.nextInt();